# How to mount volume inside child docker created by parent docker sharing docker.sock

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a wrapper container to build and run a set of containers using a docker-compose I cannot modify. The docker-compose mounts several volumes, but when starting the docker-compose from inside of the wrapper docker, the volumes are still mounted from the host since the docker .sock is volume mounted to be the host's docker.sock.

I would like to not have to use full docker-in-docker due to all the problems associated with it outlined in [jpetazzo's article](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).

I would also like to avoid `volume-from` since I cannot edit the docker-compose file mentioned previously.

Is there a way to get this snippet to correctly use the parent docker's file instead of going to the host filesystem and mounting it from there?

```
FROM docker:latest

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/parent/ && echo "This is from the parent docker" > /tmp/parent/parent.txt
CMD docker run -v /tmp/parent/parent.txt:/root/parent.txt --rm ubuntu:18.04 bash -c "cat /root/parent.txt"
```

when run with a command akin to this:

```
docker build -t parent . && docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock parent
```

Comment: `docker run -v` bind-mounted paths are _always_ the host's paths; you can't use this to mount one container's filesystem space on to another.  Why can't you edit the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Make your paths the same on the host and inside of the docker image, e.g.

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /home/user:/home/user -w /home/user/project parent_image ...
```

By mounting the volume as /home/user in the same location inside the image, a command like `docker-compose up` with relative bind mounts will use the container path names when talking to the docker socket, which will match the paths on the host.