# Weird bind mounting behaviour with docker-compose inside a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following structure,

```
cht@dell-laptop [docker-compose-test] $ tree
.
├── config
│   └── file
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Dockerfile

1 directory, 3 files
cht@dell-laptop [docker-compose-test] $ cat Dockerfile 
FROM docker/compose:alpine-1.27.4
ADD . /infra
WORKDIR /infra
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-compose", "up"]
cht@dell-laptop [docker-compose-test] $ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "3.8"
services:
  test:
    image: debian:buster-slim
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    command: sh -c "ls -l /config && cat /config/file"
    network_mode: host
cht@dell-laptop [docker-compose-test] $ cat config/file 
123
```

`docker-compose up` works as I would expect, from my *host machine*,

```
cht@dell-laptop [docker-compose-test] $ docker-compose up
Starting docker-compose-test_test_1 ... done
Attaching to docker-compose-test_test_1
test_1  | total 4
test_1  | -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 4 Nov 26 16:52 file
test_1  | 123
docker-compose-test_test_1 exited with code 0
```

But when I run the same thing from `docker/compose:alpine-1.27.4`, weirdness happens,

```
cht@dell-laptop [docker-compose-test] $ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock compose-weird
Starting infra_test_1 ... done
Attaching to infra_test_1
test_1  | total 0
test_1  | cat: /config/file: No such file or directory
infra_test_1 exited with code 1
```

Same thing happens from inside the container,

```
cht@dell-laptop [docker-compose-test] $ docker run --entrypoint sh --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock compose-weird
/infra # docker-compose up
Starting infra_test_1 ... done
Attaching to infra_test_1
test_1  | total 0
test_1  | cat: /config/file: No such file or directory
infra_test_1 exited with code 1
```

My hunch is that the bind mount to my host's Docker socket is somehow confusing the location of directories. Unfortunately, I can't find any information about what's going wrong with search engines.

Comment: The Docker daemon is the thing that interprets `docker run -v` options, and so it always mounts host system paths (from its own host, if you have a remote or VM-based Docker).  You can't mount a directory from one container into another, unless you have out-of-band knowledge that the directory has a specific host location or is in a named volume.

Comment: ([How to mount volume inside child docker created by parent docker sharing docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155816/how-to-mount-volume-inside-child-docker-created-by-parent-docker-sharing-docker) has a workaround.)

Comment: Huh, I suspected this. Thanks for the pointer to the other answer it gave me an idea. This answers my question, though I'm not sure how to credit you properly from the comments.